# Jooq java api, convert datetime to timezone in select query

Tags: spring-boot, jooq

Getting some issues with org.jooq api. Saving data into DB, in UTC format for timestamptz fields. When fetching the same from db, there is a way in postgres. 
`select id, created_datetime at time zone 'pst' from account.`

Is there any way to achieve the same into jooq ?

`selectStep = selectStep.select(fieldName).as(aliasName))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While searching for the support related with 'AT TIME ZONE' in jooq api.
 I found in github this feature is on the roadmap.

https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7238

May be helpful to others.